# Validate a number by taking a user input

Tags: python, validation

I am new to programming and I wanted to write a code, and it turned out like this: (btw, bsn number is a registration number in my country and with this code I try to validate a random bsn number)

```
check_digits = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, -1]
bsn = input('Which bsn number do you want to check?')
total = 0

def has_valid_bsn_length(bsn):
    len(bsn) == 9
    if len(bsn) != 9:
        print('Not a valid bsn number')
    else:
        return bsn


def has_valid_check_digit(bsn):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        digit = int(bsn[i])
        result = digit * check_digits[i]
        total = result

if total % 11 ==0:
    print('Valid bsn')
else:
    print('Not a valid bsn number')
```

When I try this code, no answer appears. Does any of you know how I can change the code so it works properly?

Comment: Are you sure your code is executing? In case you missed it, you are not calling `has_valid_bsn_length` and `has_valid_check_digit` functions

Comment: I need those two to be be methods, I thought I did it correctly, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have a syntax error on line 6: `len(bsn) == 9`
Also you have to call your functions. As of now you have just defined them.
Add calls like that: `result = has_valid_check_digit(bsn)`

And your second function does not return any value.

Comment: that might not be the answer considering OP does not get an output but does not get syntax error